# Fastify Error: ERR_AVVIO_PLUGIN_TIMEOUT: Plugin did not start in time

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

I'm following a Fastify tutorial, everything has been going well so far (*connected to Database, routes working, etc.)* however when attempting to add the `notesDAL` I'm receiving the following error:

`Error: ERR_AVVIO_PLUGIN_TIMEOUT: plugin did not start in time: /routes/notes/notesDAL.js. You may have forgotten to call 'done' function or to resolve a Promise`

The code is exactly the same as the tutorial, so I assume it's perhaps outdated but I'm lost. I've tried a few different ways and seem to constantly face errors. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

**notes.js**

```js
"use strict";

const NotesDAL = require("./notesDAL");

module.exports = async function (fastify, opts) {
  const notesDAL = NotesDAL(fastify.db);
  fastify.route({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/",
    handler: async (request, reply) => {
      const { title, body } = request.body;
      const newNote = await notesDAL.createNote(title, body);
      return newNote;
    },
  });
};
```

**notesDAL.js**

```js
const NotesDAL = (db) => {
  const createNote = async (title, body) => {
    const { id } = await db.one(
      "INSERT INTO notes (title, body) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING id",
      [title, body]
    );
    return { id, title, body };
  };
  return { createNote };
};
module.exports = NotesDAL;
```

If it matters, the folder structure is:

```
/app.js
/plugins/db.js
/routes/notes/notes.js
/routes/notes/notesDAL.js
```

---

**Edit:**

I've gotten it working however I am sure it's not the right way to do things, it looks very odd.

**notesDAL.js**

```js
const NotesDAL = (db) => {}
```

updated to:

```js
const NotesDAL = async (db) => {}
```

**notes.js**

```js
const newNote = await notesDAL.createNote(title, body)
```

updated to:

```js
const newNote = await (await.notesDAL).createNote(title, body)
```

As I mentioned, this looks bad but appears to be working. I'd still like to know a better method of doing this.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using fastify-autoload?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon I don’t believe so, the project was setup by the fastify-cli so potentially it’s included in that?

Comment: Could you check the package.json?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon your right, fastify-autoload is part of the fastify-cli project creation. So yes I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that by creating the project with fastify-cli I was using fastify-autoload which prevented this from working.

AutoLoad can ignore the DAL files by adding the following to `app.js` when it registers AutoLoad:

```js
ignorePattern: /.*(DAL).js/,
```

It then works successfully. Alternatively, I can move `notesDAL.js` to a folder called `services` and it works. So the folder structure would be:

```
/app.js
/plugins/db.js
/routes/notes/notes.js
/services/notesDAL.js
```